# C++ list<T>::iterator cant be used in derived class template

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, iterator, g++

g++ compiler gives this **error: expected `;' before 'it'**

```
template <typename T>
class myList : public std::list<T>
{   
public:

  void foo () 
  { 
    std::list<T>::iterator it;       // compiler error as above mentioned, why ???
  }
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In g++. whenever in a template you see the error:

```
error: expected ';' before 'it'
```

suspect you need a typename:

```
typename std::list<T>::iterator it;
```

This is needed when in a template you have a new type declared (in this case the list iterator) which is dependant on one or more of the template parameters. The need is not unique to g++ BTW, it's part of standard C++.

Comment: @anon: Do by change have a list of cases at hand where the typename is mandatory. Cheers (+1)

Answer (score 10):

Neil's given you your answer. That said, you might want to make a slew of typedef's and use those, so your work doesn't become so tedious (and it increases readability):

```
template <typename T>
class myList : public std::list<T>
{   
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const T const_value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const_value_type& const_reference;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;

    typedef std::list<T> base_container;
    typedef typename base_container::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename base_container::const_iterator const_iterator;

    void foo () 
    { 
        iterator it; // easy peasy
    }
};
```

It's quite common to be liberal with your use of typedef's.

Also, inheriting from a standard container might be a bad idea, since they aren't really made for such a thing. For example, a free function is often the [best choice](http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/letter-the-fifth/) if you're looking for some extensions to a container.

Comment: Thanx. This definitly got me some more insight.

Comment: Thanks for this nice little article, it is helped me alot!